# If $\sum_{r=1}^5 cos(rx)=5$ find the number solutions it has in $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

if $$\sum_{r=1}^5 \cos(rx)=5$$

then find the number of solutions it has in $[0,2\pi]$.
I've tried two different methods to find the solution(s), but both of which are proving to be very lengthy.

**Method 1 :**

Attempted to express everything in terms of $\cos(x) \text{ and } \sin(x)$
, so the summation would be :

$$\cos(x) +2\cos^2(x)-1+4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)+(2\cos^2x-1)^2-(2\sqrt{1-\cos^2x} \cos x)^2+((4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x))(2\cos^2x-1)-(3\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}-4\sin^3(x))(2\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}\cos(x)))=5$$

which I can then solve by substituting $u=\cos(x)$ which is very lengthy .

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, I tried expressing some sums as a product which led me to
$$2\cos(x)(\cos(2x)+\cos(3x))+\cos(5x)=5$$, which I'm unable to simplify further.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Hint: $\cos(rx) \leq 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps , It's obvious that the sum is 5 when $x=0$, and $x=2\pi$, but can't there be more than 2 solutions?

Comment: If the sum is equal to $5$ and each of the FIVE terms cannot be larger than $1$. What does that tell you?

Comment: oh yeah, never mind. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Klaus mentioned, each of the terms in the sum is $\leq 1$. Hence $cos(rx) = 1 \; \forall r$. Solving them independently gives us $x = 2a \pi = \frac{2b}{2} \pi = \frac{2c}{3} \pi = \frac{2d}{4} \pi = \frac{2e}{5} \pi$ where $a, b, c, d, e \in \mathbb{I}$. It is clear that $x = 2 n \pi$ which gives the solutions $0, 2 \pi$ in $[0, 2 \pi]$.